# Playframework - querying and displaying results from multi-table join

Tags: jpa, playframework

I'm a newcomer to java and the play framework (I'm using play 1.2.2 with a local MySQL5 database). I'm trying to query a couple of tables in a database and display the table join results on a web page.

This is what I have in the various bits:

*Controller* :-

```
public static void index() {
        List<Mutation> mutation_list= Mutation.getDisorderGene();
        render(mutation_list);       
    }
```

*Model* :-

```
public class Mutation extends Model {

  public static List<Mutation> getDisorderGene() {
    EntityManager entityManager = play.db.jpa.JPA.em();
    List<Mutation> muts = entityManager.createNativeQuery("select disorder_name, gene_name from Disorder,Mutation where Disorder.id = Mutation.disorder_id order by disorder_name, gene_name").getResultList();
    return muts;
  }
```

*View* :-

```
#{list items:mutation_list, as:'mutation'}
                    <tr>
                        <td>${mutation.disorder_name}</td>
                        <td>${mutation.gene_name}</td>
                    </tr>
 #{/list}
```

And this is the error message I get!

> Template execution error
>
> Execution error occured in template /app/views/Stu/index.html.
>   Exception raised was MissingPropertyException : Exception evaluating
>   property 'disorder_name' for java.util.Arrays$ArrayList, Reason:
>   groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: disorder_name
>   for class: java.lang.String.

I'm unsure where the problem lies. Is it with the JPA table join query or is something wrong in the view.

Are there any changes in the view I can make to display the columns?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A native query that selects multiple columns by default returns them as `Object[]`, thus your `getDisorderGene()` should return a `List<Object[]>`, and your template should look as follows:

```
#{list items:mutation_list, as:'mutation'}
                    <tr>
                        <td>${mutation[0]}</td>
                        <td>${mutation[1]}</td>
                    </tr>
 #{/list}
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you put the as clausule...

```
select disorder_name as NameMyPropertyModelClass, gene_name as NameMyPropertyModelClass 
from  Disorder,Mutation 
where Disorder.id = Mutation.disorder_id order by disorder_name, gene_name
```