# displaying list of choices in a page using play framework

Tags: java, playframework, blogs

I am creating simple blog web application using play framework and i want to display in the main page a list of categories so that when user choose a category and respond to action when a choice is clicked.
so, how i can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a simple query would probably do the trick. Depending on how you have set up your Model classes, this may be a JPQL or a native query.

This other answer may give you some tips - [Playframework - querying and displaying results from multi-table join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488026/playframework-querying-and-displaying-results-from-multi-table-join), or simply search for Play Framework JPQL and Playframework Native Query on google to get more info.

Answer (score 0):

You have a long way to go. 
Why don't start with the [Play YABE tutorial example from here](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/home)